# How to resolve Spark java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while writing out in delta format?

Tags: java, apache-spark, heap-memory, delta-lake

I am loading around 4GB of data from parquet files into a Spark DF. Loading takes few hundred millisecs. Then I register the DF as a table to Execute SQL queries.
`sparkDF = sqlContext.read.parquet("<path>/*.parquet")`
`sparkDF.registerTempTable("sparkDF")`

One of those which is a selective query with 60 columns in the select list gave out of memory exception.

```
spark.sql("select <60 columns list> from sessions where endtime >= '2019-07-01 00:00:00' and endtime < '2019-07-01 03:00:00' and id = '<uuid>'").show()
```

```
[Stage 12:>                                                      (0 + 36) / 211]2019-09-16 21:18:45,583 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 25.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 1608)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

When I remove some of the columns from the select list, it is getting executed successfully. I tried to increase the spark.executor.memory and spark.driver.memory to about 16g. But the issue could not be resolved.

Then I updated the spark version to the latest one 2.4.4. It no more gives the error now.

But with the same updated version when I write the same DF in delta format, I am getting the same out of memory error.

```
sessions.write.format("delta").save("/usr/spark-2.4.4/data/data-delta/")
```

```
[Stage 5:>                                                        (0 + 36) / 37]2019-09-18 18:58:04,362 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 21.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 109)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.<init>(DecompressorStream.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.<init>(DecompressorStream.java:71)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.NonBlockedDecompressorStream.<init>(NonBlockedDecompressorStream.java:36)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.SnappyCodec.createInputStream(SnappyCodec.java:75)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.CodecFactory$HeapBytesDecompressor.decompress(CodecFactory.java:109)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ColumnChunkPageReadStore$ColumnChunkPageReader$1.visit(ColumnChunkPageReadStore.java:93)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ColumnChunkPageReadStore$ColumnChunkPageReader$1.visit(ColumnChunkPageReadStore.java:88)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.page.DataPageV1.accept(DataPageV1.java:95)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ColumnChunkPageReadStore$ColumnChunkPageReader.readPage(ColumnChunkPageReadStore.java:88)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl.readPage(ColumnReaderImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl.checkRead(ColumnReaderImpl.java:525)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl.consume(ColumnReaderImpl.java:638)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl.<init>(ColumnReaderImpl.java:353)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReadStoreImpl.newMemColumnReader(ColumnReadStoreImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReadStoreImpl.getColumnReader(ColumnReadStoreImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.parquet.io.RecordReaderImplementation.<init>(RecordReaderImplementation.java:271)
    at org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO$1.visit(MessageColumnIO.java:147)
    at org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO$1.visit(MessageColumnIO.java:109)
    at org.apache.parquet.filter2.compat.FilterCompat$NoOpFilter.accept(FilterCompat.java:165)
    at org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO.getRecordReader(MessageColumnIO.java:109)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.checkRead(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:137)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:222)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ParquetRecordReader.java:207)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
```

Any better suggestions/improvements on this will be helpful in resolving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the Spark version 2.4.4, increasing only the driver memory at runtime, helped in resolving the issue.

`pyspark --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.3.0 --driver-memory 5g`

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the amount of RAM that the VM can use. The VM options for that are:

```
 -Xms: sets the minimum memory usage. Syntax: -Xms2048m        (2 GB of memory)

 -Xmx: sets the maximum memory usage. Syntax: -Xmx2048m
```

I'm not sure if that would fix your problem, but you should give it a try.

Comment: Actually I think -Xms2048m means 2GB of memory

Answer (score -1):

Solution to increasing driver and executor memory is very temporary solution.Also its all about parallelism.You don't need 16gb memory for driver.

Instead of spark.sql("select <60 columns list> from sessions where endtime >= '2019-07-01 00:00:00' and endtime < '2019-07-01 03:00:00' and id = ''").show() you should 
use spark.sql("select * from sessions where endtime >= '2019-07-01 00:00:00' and endtime < '2019-07-01 03:00:00' and id = ''").show(60)

Comment: I tried that too. It was the same error with this as well. Also, the initial 60columns are random and not the 1st 60. So show(60) would only display the first 60 columns and would not always work.